# Constructor Null safety in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

Tell me please. Why is pr2 null and not str1 by default?

```
void main() {
  var house = Home(pr1: 4, pr3: 5);
  house.printDate();
}

class Home {
  int pr1=1;
  String? pr2 = 'str1';
  int pr3=3;
  Home({required this.pr1, this.pr2, required this.pr3});

  void printDate() {
    print('The pr1: $pr1');
    print('The pr2: $pr2');
    print('The pr3: $pr3');
  }
}
```

The pr1: 4 The pr2: null The pr3: 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because optional parameters are by default `null` unless otherwise specified in the constructor definition. If you want to declare another default value, you need to use this syntax:

```dart
void main() {
  var house = Home(pr1: 4, pr3: 5);
  house.printDate();
  // The pr1: 4
  // The pr2: str1
  // The pr3: 5
}

class Home {
  int pr1=1;
  String? pr2;
  int pr3=3;
  Home({required this.pr1, this.pr2 = 'str1', required this.pr3});

  void printDate() {
    print('The pr1: $pr1');
    print('The pr2: $pr2');
    print('The pr3: $pr3');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I refactored your code for readability and would drop the first solution using if-else statement

```
class Home {
  //initialize the variables using the final keyword
  final int? pr1;
  final String? pr2;
  final int? pr3;
  
  //set the constructors
  Home({required this.pr1, this.pr2, required this.pr3});
  
void printDate(){
  //using the pr1 value
  print('The pr1: $pr1');
  //perfoming a runtime assertation for dev
  //assert(pr2 == null);//if the value for pr2 is null; it run smoothly
  //using if-else statement, I can tell wht is shows as outcome
  if (pr2 == null){
    print('The pr2: str1');
  }else{print('The pr2: $pr2');}//I would be rewriting this as a tenary operator


  //using the pr3 value
  print('The pr3: $pr3');
}
}
//the app starts ro run from here  
void main(){
  var house = Home(pr1:5,pr3:6,);
  house.printDate();
}
```

From the above, you can see that when the condition for pr2 is null, it displays the text 'str1' and if it is not null, it displays the value of pr2.
Hope this helps alot.

Comment: Not only does this not answer the question, it completely misrepresents the code associated with the question. Also, ironically, your "refactored for readability" efforts have made your code even harder to read.

Comment: Hello Abion, Ideally according to dart documentation, it is best to use comments so it can be readable, I said in the second answer, null safety asides, if you have issues with the code, you could have said so, not being modestly sarcastic, we are all here to learn and make contributions, I explained to him that the 'null' is there cause it is not safe practice to assign values to variables in consturctors as that is what it arrives at after compiling, and showed an easier alternative. please be mindful of how you comment, thank you.

Comment: Comments by themselves don't make code readable. Your inconsistent use of whitespace and indentation do far more harm to readability than comments could rectify. Also your answer provided an opinionated theoretical reason why parameters should or shouldn't be null when the question was asking why `pr1` was not null and `pr2` was null, which is a technical question rather than a theoretical one, and that is why I said your answer does not answer the question. You were more interested in "fixing" OP's code than you were in answering the question they actually asked, hence the downvote.

Comment: And finally, your comment about how it's "not safe" to assign values to variables within constructors is patently false. Constructors are precisely where variables are assigned values, and Dart's features of default parameter values and initializer lists are effectively syntactic sugar for doing precisely that.

Answer (score -2):

The second way would be to use a tenary operator to check for null

```
class Home {
  //initialize the variables using the final keyword
  final int? pr1;
  final String? pr2;
  final int? pr3;

  //set the constructors
  Home({required this.pr1, this.pr2, required this.pr3});

  void printDate() {
    //using the pr1 value
    print('The pr1: $pr1');
//pr2 check for null safety using tenary
    pr2 == null ? print('The Pr2: str1'):print('The pr2:$pr2');
    //using the pr3 value
    print('The pr3: $pr3');
  }
}

//the app starts ro run from here
void main() {
  var house = Home(
    pr1: 5,
    pr3: 6,
  );
  house.printDate();
}
```

What does tenary mean? simply put, think of it as a logic condition, a form of if-else but in an easier way, the way to express this is:

```
 condition?expression1:expression2;
```

if the condition is true, expression 1 runs, if the condition is false, expression 2 runs.
To answer your question, from dart 2.12, it became null safe, it is not a safe practice to variables to constructors. I would be glad to explain further if the need be.

Comment: Again, the question has nothing to do with how to check whether `pr2` is or isn't null. It's a technical question asking _*why*_ `pr2` is null and `pr1` is not, which as julemand explained is because `pr1` is a required named parameter while `pr2` is an optional named parameter. Also, don't post a second answer when this is just an extension to your first answer.